# NSURLConnection ignores Keep-Alive timeout?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, keep-alive

I'm converting my app to use HTTPS and would like to avoid the handshake cost as much as possible by keeping open a long-lived connection.

From reading the web and other answers on stack overflow it appears NSURLConnection should transparently keep the underlying socket open if the server responds with Connection: keep-alive and Keep-Alive: timeout=N.

However I am seeing that my connections are only kept open for around 10 seconds. My Keep-Alive response is set to much more than this. I am also sending Connection: keep-alive in my request headers.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I *really* don't want to have to use CFNetwork to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways:

As Tyler states in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424800/19679):

> You can specify a timeout in your `NSURLRequest` object.  One way to
>   do this is to construct it via the
>   [`requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424800/19679) method.  (You can
>   pass in the default `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` cachePolicy
>   parameter if you don't want to worry about that part.)  The timeout is
>   a floating-point value in seconds, as are basically all time intervals
>   in the iPhone SDK.
>
> Also make sure your `NSURLConnection`'s delegate is set and responds
>   to the [`connection:didFailWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection:didFailWithError:) method.  A connection
>   always calls either this method or `connectionDidFinishLoading:` upon
>   connection completion.

Or do what Kris suggests in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834768/19679):

> ASIHTTPRequest has an expirePersistentConnections method. It may do
>   what you're looking for.
>
> It's not a drop-in replacement for NSURLConnection, but it's not too
>   hard to port code from NSURLConnection to ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Please do not copy the words of others without proper attribution. I've edited the above to do so, but please make sure you do this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The 10s problem got fixed in iOS7. I was having same problem and was following the bug. It got fixed in iOS 6 point some version.

Comment: iOS 9.2.1: It's not fixed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318/error-domain-nsurlerrordomain-code-1005-the-network-connection-was-lost/25996971#25996971